# How to Resize Image in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

How to Resize Image in custom Category Collection Magento 1.9

```
 $cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2)->getChildren();
        $catIds = explode(',',$cats);

        $categories = array();
        foreach($catIds as $catId) {
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId); 
            $categories[$category->getName()] = array(
            'url' => $category->getUrl(),
            'description' => $category->getDescription(),
            'img' => $category->getImageUrl()
            );
        }

        ksort($categories, SORT_STRING);
```

Call Image as below now i want to resize my image.

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $data['img']; ?>" />
```

Any one idea how to resize images.

Answer (score 4):

Nikul, Magento **does not have** any **default resize function** for category like product.

So, you need to use `Varien_Image` class for this purpose.

**Just like below example:**

```
$image = new Varien_Image('/full/fs/path/to/image.jpg');

// you cannot use method chaining with Varien_Image
$image->constrainOnly(false);
$image->keepFrame(true);
// avoid black borders by setting background colour
$image->backgroundColor(array(255,255,255));
$image->keepAspectRatio(true);
$image->resize(216, 139);
$image->save('/full/fs/path/to/save/to.jpg');
```

Comment: From Above my code how to get image resize.

Comment: As Per Above code how to get resize in my code..

Answer (score 3):

Override category model `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` file local

after add bellow function override file

```
/**
    * Retrieve ResizedImage...
    * 
    * @param int $width
    * @param int $height
    * @param int $quality
    * @return string
    */
    public function getResizedImage($width, $height = 135, $quality = 100)
    {
        if (!$this->getImage())
            return false;

        $imageUrl = Mage::getBaseDir ('media') .DS. "catalog" .DS. "category" .DS. $this->getImage();
        if (! is_file ( $imageUrl ))
            return false;

        $imageResized = Mage::getBaseDir ( 'media' ) . DS . "catalog" . DS . "product" . DS . "cache" .DS. "category" .DS. "resized" .DS. $this->getImage();// Because clean Image cache function works in this folder only
        if (! file_exists($imageResized) && file_exists($imageUrl) || file_exists($imageUrl) && filemtime($imageUrl) > filemtime($imageResized)) {
            $imageObj = new Varien_Image($imageUrl);
            $imageObj->constrainOnly(true);
            $imageObj->keepAspectRatio(true);
            $imageObj->keepFrame(false);
            $imageObj->quality($quality);
            $imageObj->resize($width, $height);
            $imageObj->save($imageResized);
        }

        if(file_exists($imageResized)){
            return Mage::getBaseUrl('media') ."/catalog/product/cache/category/resized/" . $this->getImage();
        }else{
            return $this->getImageUrl();
        }
    }

    /**
    * Retrieve getResizedThumbnail...
    * 
    * @param int $width
    * @param int $height
    * @param int $quality
    * @return string
    */
    public function getResizedThumbnail($width, $height = 135, $quality = 100)
    {
        if (!$this->getThumbnail())
            return false;

        $imageUrl = Mage::getBaseDir ('media') .DS. "catalog" .DS. "category" .DS. $this->getThumbnail();
        if (! is_file ( $imageUrl ))
            return false;

        $imageResized = Mage::getBaseDir ( 'media' ) . DS . "catalog" . DS . "product" . DS . "cache" .DS. "category" .DS. "resized" .DS. $this->getThumbnail();// Because clean Image cache function works in this folder only
        if (! file_exists($imageResized) && file_exists($imageUrl) || file_exists($imageUrl) && filemtime($imageUrl) > filemtime($imageResized)) {
            $imageObj = new Varien_Image($imageUrl);
            $imageObj->constrainOnly(true);
            $imageObj->keepAspectRatio(true);
            $imageObj->keepFrame(false);
            $imageObj->quality($quality);
            $imageObj->resize($width, $height);
            $imageObj->save($imageResized);
        }

        if(file_exists($imageResized)){
            return Mage::getBaseUrl('media') ."/catalog/product/cache/category/resized/" . $this->getThumbnail();
        }else{
            return $this->getThumbnail();
        }
    }
```

**Call Image as below now You want to resize my image:**

```
<?php $categoryId 101; $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId); ?>


<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $category->getResizedThumbnail(135,135); ?>" />



<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $category->getResizedImage(135,135); ?>" />
```